# Angular 2 first app works, second app don't

Tags: html, angular

I tried to create a angular2 application that loads two components.
The first component called ***app*** works fine.
but the second component don't (called ***app-second***).

- **index.html code**

  ```
  <h1>Demo of Angular 2 using ASP.NET 5 with Visual Studio 2015</h1>
  <app>Loading...</app>
  <br />
  <app-second>Loading...</app-second>
  ```
- **app.ts code**

  ```
      import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

      @Component({
              selector: 'app',
              template: 'My First Angular 2 App'
      })

      export class AppComponent {}
  ```
- **app-second.ts code**

  ```
      import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

      @Component({
              selector: 'app-second',
              template: 'My First Angular 2 App'
      })

      export class AppSecondComponent{}
  ```
- ***A Snapshot***:
  [image: Snapshot of my application]

Can anybody tell me what is the error here?

Thanx.

Comment: The most important part is missing in your question. How do you initialize the App?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bootstrap your second app too.

```
//Importing bootstrap to instantiate your app
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'

//importing the components you need to load
import {AppComponent} from './app/app'
import {AppSecondComponent} from './app/app-second'

//instantiating the components
bootstrap(AppComponent);
bootstrap(AppSecondComponent);
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bootstrap both components

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, ...);
bootstrap(AppSecondComponent, ...);
```